# Slow Performance within While Loop when Updating MYSQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

The following code runs incredibly slowly when performing a WHILE LOOP using data from table `product` and updating another table `stock_figures` within the same database.

The code loops through each row in `product` taking the value from `product_id` and `wholesale_price` and then performs some calculations on the `product` table before updating the `stock_figures` table with the values.

I'd be grateful of any suggestions which would improve the performance of my queries.

**PHP WHILE LOOP**

```
<?

// Retrieve data from database
$loop = " SELECT product_id, wholesale_price FROM product";
$query= mysql_query($loop);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
        $id = $row[0];
        $price = $row[1];

?>
```

**QUERIES WITHIN WHILE LOOP**

```
<?

        $bawtry_stock = "

        SELECT product_id,
        ( kids_uk_j_105 + kids_c_17 + kids_c_18 + kids_c_19 + ... etc ) 

        AS SUM FROM product WHERE product_id = '$id'";

        $result_bawtry = mysql_query($bawtry_stock) or die (mysql_error());
        $line = mysql_fetch_row($result_bawtry);
        $bawtry = $line[1];

        $chain_stock = "

        SELECT product_id, 
        (quantity_c_size_26_chain + quantity_c_size_28_chain + quantity_c_size_30_chain +
        ... etc )

        AS SUM FROM product WHERE product_id = '$id'";

        $result_chain = mysql_query($chain_stock) or die (mysql_error());
        $line = mysql_fetch_row($result_chain);
        $chain = $line[1];

        /*
         * Declare the total value of all pairs from Bawtry, Chain
         */

        $totalpairs = $chain + $bawtry;

        /*
         * Insert values for stock to write to databse
         * Total stock for Bawtry, Chain
         * Total value of stock for Bawtry, Chain
         *
         */

        $bawtry_value = (float)($bawtry * $price);

        $chain_value = (float)($chain * $price);

        $total_value = (float)($price * ($bawtry + $chain));

        $sql2="

        UPDATE stock_figures SET 
        bawtry_stock='$bawtry',
        chain_stock='$chain',
        totalstock='$totalpairs',
        bawtry_value='$bawtry_value',
        chain_value='$chain_value',
        totalvalue='$total_value'

        WHERE id='$id'";

        $result2=mysql_query($sql2) or die (mysql_error());



?>

// close while loop
<? } ?>
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
$sql = "SELECT product_id, wholesale_price,
        (kids_uk_j_105 + kids_c_17 + kids_c_18 + kids_c_19 + kids_c_20 + kids_c_21 +
        ... )

        AS bawtry,

        (quantity_c_size_26_chain + quantity_c_size_28_chain + quantity_c_size_30_chain +
        ... )

        AS chain from product";

        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

        while ($line=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 

        {
            $id = $line['product_id'];
            $price = $line['wholesale_price'];
            $bawtry = $line['bawtry'];
            $chain = $line['chain'];

        /*
         * Declare the total value of all pairs from Bawtry, Chain 
         */

        $totalpairs = $chain + $bawtry;

        /*
         * Insert values for stock to write to database
         * Total stock for Bawtry, Chain
         * Total value of stock for Bawtry, Chain
         *
         */

        $bawtry_value = (float)($bawtry * $price);

        $chain_value = (float)($chain * $price);

        $total_value = (float)($price * ($bawtry + $chain));

        $sql2="

        UPDATE stock_figures SET 
        bawtry_stock='$bawtry',
        chain_stock='$chain',
        totalstock='$totalpairs',
        bawtry_value='$bawtry_value',
        chain_value='$chain_value',
        totalvalue='$total_value'

        WHERE id='$id'";

        $result2=mysql_query($sql2) or die (mysql_error());
```

However, it's still taking an absolute age to complete. It seems to run really fast when I comment out the UPDATE statement at the end. Obviously this needs to remain in the code, so I'll probably run the whole thing as a cronjob.

**Unless any further improvements can be suggested?**

Comment: Use a limit in SQL and paging? For selecting

Comment: why not work with associate arrays? query once for both tables and store those values in separate arrays, then loop over the arrays

Comment: agree with using limits, i just wonder what amount of data are you working with, and what's your memory limit, and i dont believe associative arrays are gonna help at all, if anything they will make it worse, because of more data in loop from result set

Comment: I think you should try to avoid doing calculations on top of data retrieved from the database to update data in the database in your php code; you can use `JOIN` in an `UPDATE` statement to get those other relations, avoiding extra php code and making fewer calls (I think actually this could be narrowed down to only one single update, avoiding a loop completely) to the db should speed it up significantly

Comment: @aphextwix - do you have set `id` as primary id in `stock_figures` table?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek - yes Marcin.

Comment: So you should reconsider what I wrote and use Mysqli prepared statements - more at http://php.net//manual/pl/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php But first you should remove your update code and make sure this loop run without update query as fast as you expect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you doing a lot of wasted selects.

You first select some data from table products, then for each row you select again from the same table. Twice. Then finally inserting this into another table, stock_figures.

And the only operation you are doing is adding lots of figures together.

All of this can be done in a single query.

```
select product_id,
       whole_sale_price, 
       sum(kids_uk_j_105, 
           kids_c_17,
           ...) as bawtry,
       sum(quantity_c_size_26_chain, 
           quantity_c_size_28_chain, 
           ...) as chain
  from products;
```

If this still is taking lots of time you need to check some server settings and also number of rows

Every write you make is a transaction and depending on your ACID-level it might be slow to do commits. Change innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit to 2 will speed up writes.

You are doing a full table scan on products-table. I guess this is intended but if that table is big reading it will take a while, and writing all those rows back to stock_figures is going to take even longer.

Consider another approach. For each write (insert, update or delete) to products have a trigger update the corresponding row in stock_figures. Not only will it eliminate the batch job, it will also make stock_figures be correct at any given time.

Comment: +1 for being the only one here who's smart enough to see this task can be achieved by a single query instead of tons of obsolete spaghetti PHP code.

Comment: +1 I've added it also to my answer (I haven't noticed earlier that those 2 queries are for the same DB table)

Comment: Thanks Andreas - Please see my updated code above. This is still taking forever to run. At the moment it's 5 minutes and counting ... Is there anything further I could improve?

Comment: @Andreas - it seemed the performance was just slow on my XAMPP server. Once I ran the script on my hosting server, it became really fast. Completed in around 10 secs. Thanks again for all your advice.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is:

```
 $row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
 $id = $row[0];
 $price = $row[1];
```

I don't know if it does work for you, but you already take $rows in your `while` condition so probably you should change it into:

```
 $id = $rows['product_id'];
 $price = $row['wholesale_price'];
```

Then the next 2 queries you can combine info:

```
SELECT product_id,
        ( kids_uk_j_105 + kids_c_17 + kids_c_18 + kids_c_19 + ... etc ) 

        AS `SUM` FROM product WHERE product_id = '$id'

UNION ALL

SELECT product_id, 

        (quantity_c_size_26_chain + quantity_c_size_28_chain + quantity_c_size_30_chain +
        ... etc )

        AS `SUM` FROM product WHERE product_id = '$id'
```

or even:

```
SELECT product_id,
        ( kids_uk_j_105 + kids_c_17 + kids_c_18 + kids_c_19 + ... etc ) 

        AS `SUM1`,
        (quantity_c_size_26_chain + quantity_c_size_28_chain + quantity_c_size_30_chain +
        ... etc )
       AS `SUM2`
  FROM product WHERE product_id = '$id'
```

because those 2 queries are run on the same table.

But in fact you can use just one query to get everything about your products as **Andreas Wederbrand** pointed in his answer.

But there are more problems:

1. You use old `mysql_` function instead of `mysqli_` or `PDO` and your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection
2. For each product you run 2 extra queries (select with union all if you go my way and update).
3. I don't know how many products you have, but if you have for example 1000 products or 10000 products you cannot expect it will be very fast. In that case you should somehow run your script in cron or refresh the page and do the job for small amount of products (for example for 10 or 100 at one time)
4. You should also consider if your database structure is the best one. Usually using many columns as you here `kids_uk_j_105`, `kids_c_17`, `kids_c_18` is not the best choice.

I hope you have set key primary_id at `product_id` column as least.

Comment: Thanks for this - yes 'product_id' is set as primary key.

Answer (score 0):

When executing many SQL commands, parsing them takes some time. You can reduce this overhead by using http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
How much you gain, depends on case.

Prepared statements are also good for security reasons.

This answer does not void other answers here. Try to gain efficiency by reducing number of queries, analyzing their work, merging them if possible etc.